# Adding TextInputLayout to my Android Studio Project causes my design view to go blank

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to switch out of EditText to the more sophisticated TextInputLayout/TextInputEditText
and whenever I add a TextInputLayout it causes my design view to go blank despite refreshing, invalidating caches, and syncing project with Gradle Files.

Attached is the current view with TextInputLayout/TextInputEditText implemented

[Non-working design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFO7i.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem.. The layout is visible when I show it as `tools:layout` on navigation editor and even when I switch back from somewhere it is shown for few seconds and then it disappears. The same thing happens when I change parent theme... I can even click on elements, but the whole screen is green as shown on your image. Any progress on this problem?

Comment: I opened a bug to material..

Answer (score 0):

Try using Bridge theme. Just change the parent theme of your current theme to be one of the Bridge themes. Ex:

In your `style.xml` add something like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

[Try following this official instruction on how to get started with Material components](https://m2.material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started)